# Sliding Android window (two rates)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation

I don't know how to describe this very well but I see it in a lot of apps such as Transit.

There is a main window and then a view below it such that when you scroll down, the top window slides up at a slower rate within its own view while the bottom view scrolls up at the same rate the user drags.

Is there a name for this technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the effect you are talking about is of `Coordinator Layout`. You need to implement `Coordinator Layout` and define view that you want to scroll upward.

[image]

One of the example that you can use to learn is [Mastering the Coordinator Layout](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator).
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, but this is also a lot more complex. I don't need it to merge/fade into the top toolbar or anything.

Comment: Just put the flag app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in your toolbar and you wont get the fade effect.

Comment: The fade effect isn't the problem -- I just don't need it merging with the toolbar (for an exact example of what I am trying to do please see Transit)